# ffmpeg rtsp audio streaming with h264

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, streaming, rtsp

I am using the following command to stream from my desktop-microphone via RTSP to a Wowza Streaming Cloud Server.
However, this command has video-parameters which I wish to exclude since I only want to encode audio in the stream. I am only interested using aac, a sample rate of 16000 and a bit-rate of 32000. As required by Wowza, it must be a h264 stream.

Anyone who could help me to optimize it for audio as mentioned above?

```
ffmpeg -f dshow -re -i audio="Desktop Microphone (HD-3000 - Microsoft LifeCam.)" -c:v libx264 -profile:v baseline -level 3.0 -r 24 -g 48 -keyint_min 48 -sc_threshold 0 -vb 310k -c:a aac -ab 40k -ar 44100 -ac 2 -f rtsp -muxdelay 0.1 rtsp://wowza-ipaddress:1935/app-xxx/yyyyyy
```

Comment: H.264 is a video codec. If there's no video, there's no H.264 stream to generate. All the video options in your command are inert and at best they will produce a warning by ffmpeg that they aren't applied to any output stream.

Comment: Thank you. This was actually a follow-up of this question https://superuser.com/q/1194937/54328 The problem was that the stream did not connect but by adding h264 my command managed to connect and stream

Comment: Anyway, if you would like to add your comment as a reply, I will gladly mark your reply as the solution